# QLineEdit and keyPressEvent

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm learning PyQt5 on python3 and I'm having some troubles with associating keyPressEvent to a QLineEdit.

I'd like to associate keyPressEvent to QLineEdit so that when I press a key having the LineEdit box selected an action is triggered.

Here an example of what I'd like to achieve:

- I write something in the LineEdit Box
- I press a key (say 'Enter' for example)
- What I have wrote in the LineEdit Box is printed on the terminal
- If I deselect the Box or select another object in my GUI (i.e. another LineEdit Box) and I press enter I don't trigger the previous action.

Here an example of the code where I'd like to implement this functionality:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 40, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 80, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: `Dialog.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda: print(Dialog.lineEdit.text()))`.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for that :)

Comment: @ekhumoro Should post this as an answer!